# How to fix Material-UI Dialog Textfield focus error?

Tags: reactjs, dialog, focus, material-ui, textfield

I am building an internal website at my work. After implementing Permission-based-access control, I am trying to create a place where users can create roles. The problem is this. Whenever I click on the textfield the cursor keeps disappearing. Which means I can't type a word at all.

I can enter a value by clicking the textfield and tapping on the keyboard really fast simultaneously. I am not getting any error message.

I am using the form dialog straight from https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/#form-dialogs. I import this component in a parent component to use it. It's not linked to any of my function yet.

I created extra `<input type="text" />` in both inside and outside of the Dialog tag to see if I am getting the same problem. Those `<input type="text" />` inside of Dialog tag have the same issue, but the outside one works fine.

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';

export default function FormDialog() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
        Open form dialog
      </Button>
      <input type="text" />
      <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
        <input type="text" />
        <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Subscribe</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>
            To subscribe to this website, please enter your email address here. We will send updates
            occasionally.
          </DialogContentText>
          <input type="text" />
          <TextField
            autoFocus
            margin="dense"
            id="name"
            label="Email Address"
            type="email"
            fullWidth
          />
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
            Cancel
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
            Subscribe
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any insights?

Comment: Please provide a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that reproduces your problem. The code you provided works fine on its own. I suspect something outside of the code shown is causing the whole dialog to remount as you type.

Comment: Adding the [disableEnforceFocus](https://material-ui.com/api/modal/#props) property to the dialog did the trick for me